# How to refer to a position of a column in a loop R

Tags: r

I'm having problems in this situation:

I have three data frames, just like that:

```
    df1 = data.frame(A = c(1,2,2),
                 B = c(5,4,3))

df2 = data.frame(C = c(1,2,2),
                 D = c(5,4,3))

df3 = data.frame(E = c(1,2,2),
                 'F' = c(5,4,3))
```

and I want to pass them through a loop, using this list of variables that I made:

```
df_names <- paste0("df", 1:3)
df_all <- mget(var_names, envir = globalenv())
```

but the column names differ, meaning I'm having trouble getting the average of the first and second column!

what i need is something like this:

```
for(i in 1:3){

df_mean[i] <- df_all[[i]] %>%
  mutate(mean_first_column = mean (A (or C or E)),
         mean_second_column = mean(B, D or F))


}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to create new columns or a summarised output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using either `colMeans` or `across`

```
library(dplyr)
df_mean <- vector('list', length(df_all))
for(i in seq_along(df_all)) 
    df_mean[[i]] <- df_all[[i]] %>%
          summarise(across(everything(), mean))
```

-output

```
df_mean
[[1]]
         A B
1 1.666667 4

[[2]]
         C D
1 1.666667 4

[[3]]
         E F
1 1.666667 4
```

---

If we need to specify position, either subset with `.` or `cur_data()` or `.data` (with grouping attributes, `cur_data()` or `.data` should be more appropriate

```
df_mean <- vector('list', length(df_all))
for(i in seq_along(df_all)) 
     df_mean[[i]] <- df_all[[i]] %>%
      mutate(mean_first_column = mean(cur_data()[[1]]),
            mean_second_column = mean(cur_data()[[2]]))
```

-output

```
df_mean
[[1]]
  A B mean_first_column mean_second_column
1 1 5          1.666667                  4
2 2 4          1.666667                  4
3 2 3          1.666667                  4

[[2]]
  C D mean_first_column mean_second_column
1 1 5          1.666667                  4
2 2 4          1.666667                  4
3 2 3          1.666667                  4

[[3]]
  E F mean_first_column mean_second_column
1 1 5          1.666667                  4
2 2 4          1.666667                  4
3 2 3          1.666667                  4
```

---

NOTE: `mutate` returns the whole data along with the columns created.  As `mean` is a single  value, it may be better to use `summarise`

---

In `base R`, we can loop over the `list` with `lapply` and apply `colMeans`

```
lapply(df_all, colMeans)
```

---

Or if we want to use `tidyverse` syntax`

```
library(purrr)
map(df_all, ~ .x %>%
               summarise(across(everything(), mean))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R approach. You can calculate the mean values using column position rather than column name.

```
df_mean <- data.frame(
  mean_first_column = double(0),
  mean_second_column = double(0)
)

dfs <- paste0("df", 1:3)

for (i in seq_along(dfs)) {
  df_mean[i,] <- colMeans(get(dfs[i]))
}

df_mean
#   mean_first_column mean_second_column
# 1          1.666667                  4
# 2          1.666667                  4
# 3          1.666667                  4
```

Comment: thanks for the reply but i need to use the mutate function. cur_data() solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to `across()` could be:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df1 = data.frame(A = c(1,2,2),
                 B = c(5,4,3))
df2 = data.frame(C = c(1,2,2),
                 D = c(5,4,3))
df3 = data.frame(E = c(1,2,2),
                 'F' = c(5,4,3))
df_names <- paste0("df", 1:3)
df_all <- mget(df_names, envir = globalenv())

df_all %>% 
  map(~ mutate(.x, !!!map(.x, ~ mean(.)) %>% set_names(names(.x))) )
#> $df1
#>          A B
#> 1 1.666667 4
#> 2 1.666667 4
#> 3 1.666667 4
#> 
#> $df2
#>          C D
#> 1 1.666667 4
#> 2 1.666667 4
#> 3 1.666667 4
#> 
#> $df3
#>          E F
#> 1 1.666667 4
#> 2 1.666667 4
#> 3 1.666667 4

#using summarise

df_all %>% 
  map(~ summarise(.x, !!!map(.x, ~ mean(.)) %>% set_names(names(.x))) )
#> $df1
#>          A B
#> 1 1.666667 4
#> 
#> $df2
#>          C D
#> 1 1.666667 4
#> 
#> $df3
#>          E F
#> 1 1.666667 4

#or

df_all %>% 
  map_dfc(~ summarise(.x, !!!map(.x, ~ mean(.)) %>% set_names(names(.x))) )
#>          A B        C D        E F
#> 1 1.666667 4 1.666667 4 1.666667 4
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>